# How to protect sheets using C# interop but allowing selection

Tags: c#, excel

I am currently using following options to protect the worksheet.

```
dataWorksheet.Protect(result.protectionPassword.ToString(), false, true, false, false, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true);
```

The above option protects the sheet and does not allow selection of the protected sheet.

However such protection is inconvenient when referring cell values from another sheet so i would like to protect the content (values) but allow selection of the cells.

So I recorded the macro on Excel and the option there was `DrawingObjects:true, contents:true, scenarios:true`. I have tried this combination of options but have not been successful.

The following is the documentation for interop `protect` method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel

How can I protect the worksheet in a way that selection is possible but the values cannot be tampered with?

Answer (score 0):

The only sheet protection options for xls file format is for sheet objects (DrawingObjects:true), cell content (contents:true) and scenarios (scenarios:true).

The sheet protection options for xlsx file format is more flexible and also includes the cell selection option that you need.

The Worksheet.Protect method seems to include some of the protection options available for xlsx file format, but selection of the cells is not included.

Most probably, you need to **switch to XLSX file format** and use a different library than Interop to create the Excel file.

The default behavior is to allow cell selection.